# Using ~がる in the first person

Tags: grammar

I know how ~がる constructions work in reference to subjects in the third person. However, I am a bit lost in regards to which situations necessitate the use of ~がる with the first person.

For example this sentence is correct:

> 私がアイスクリームを食べたがると、母が食べさせてくれた。

But this sentence is wrong

> 私がアイスクリームを食べたいと、母が食べさせてくれた。

I don't know why.

Upon conducting some google searches in an attempt to find the answer to this question, I found [a source](http://blog.livedoor.jp/s_izuha/archives/6284569.html) saying that one can use ~がる with the first person to narrate something that happened to them in a detached manner. Interesting but not really relevant to this particular distinction, I think. Or is it?

[This paper](https://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/nichigen/menu7_folder/symposium/pdf/8/06.pdf) also mentions the existence of the first person ~がる construction, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't say anything helpful (but I could have overlooked something).

Does anyone specifically know why 食べたがる MUST be used in the above sentences?

Comment: Just to clarify... 1) 食べがる is always ungrammatical. It must be 食べたがる. 2) In your case, saying 食べたがる means you're "showing signs" of your desire to Mom. Just thinking "I want to eat ice cream" won't make Mom do something.

Comment: "Does anyone specifically know why 食べたがる MUST be used in the above sentences?" : It's because 私がアイスクリームを食べたいと、母が食べさせてくれた implies that your mother has super natural power to detect your desire.